# GatsbyJS init with version v2.6.0?

Tags: npm, gatsby

I'm trying to create a new gatsbyjs site but I don't want to use the new v3 as I'm using a template which only supports v2.6.0 how can I run npm gatsby init on v2.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
npm install gatsby@2.6.0
```

You can read for further details about `npm-install` command at the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install).

You can clone your template and lower the Gatsby version if needed.